# Can't load JavaScript from Resource in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiwebview

I am loading a local HTML file into a UIWebView in iOS using this code

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

The page works fine, and the image linked within the HTML loads fine. However, the JavaScript linked off of the page is not loading.

The HTML, Image and JavaScript are all located in the same folder. (Resources/Html in my Project)

How can I get the JavaScript to load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that XCode was showing me a warning:

> warning: no rule to process file
>   '$(PROJECT_DIR)/html/orientation.js'
>   of type sourcecode.javascript for
>   architecture i386

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843820/iphone-uiwebview-local-resources-using-javascript-and-handling-onorientationchang/851333#851333) contains the solution. Basically, I had to tell XCode to not try and build the JavaScript files, and manually drag them to the "Copy Bundle Resources" directory.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for loading an html file which has javascript files  in the web view 
Here web is web view object and index is the html page

```
Web.delegate = self;

[Web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```