# Display offline html5 website

Tags: ios, xcode, html, ipad, uiwebview

For my business I need to be able to show a potential client a website I generate with a program called Pano2VR, which is a virtual tour program. This program takes some panoramic photos linked with each other and can generate a virtual tour out of them (as example: www.casas-fotoart.de/virtualtours ). The output this App gives can be either HTML5, Flash or both (flash if available and html5 for mobile devices, for example).

I need to be able to show that on my iPad while offline. i haven't found any solution for that so I tried to build a easy App for that, which I thought it wouldn't be complicated.

I generated a html5-only virtual tour and I droped the output into the "Suporting Files" group on the Xcode project. I added a UIWebView and on viewDidLoad I set it so it loads the html file.

The files I'm droping are like these (these inside the ipad folder):

[image]

The html file loads into the webView, but it just displays "**This content requires HTML5/CSS3, WebGL, or Adobe Flash Player Version 9 or higher.**", even though when loading these files from the net, it loads perfectly. I know this message comes from the html file.

Any idea on how to make it work will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the paths to the JS files? it probably can't load the JS files and displays this as the default message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911208/cant-load-javascript-from-resource-in-uiwebview) probably - XCode is mangling the JS files, I assume because it's trying to compile them

Comment: That was exactly it. It took me a while but it works now. Awesome! However I had to edit the xml and skin.js files. They where directing the search for pictures to the /images folder. I had to find all the references and delete the images/ string... but it was just a couple of seconds... Thanks again!