# Render HTML5 chart in WebView using Javascript

Tags: macos, webkit

I am trying to build a chart into my MacOS app, and decided that rather than using the limited options available in native objective-c, I would be better off using HTML 5, and embedding a WebView control.

I have managed to embed the WebView okay, by linking to an index.html file that is part of my application, using the following.

```
// Load the HTML content.
NSString *resourcesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *htmlPath = [resourcesPath stringByAppendingString:@"/index.html"];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]]];
```

I tested this with some simply html, so I know it is connected okay. However, when embedding some more complex code, which includes some CSS and JS, it doesn't render. If I load the `index.html` in a safari window, it renders the chart.

Is there something more I have to do to make the Javascript execute?

For extra detail, the chart uses JQPlot, and the content of the index file is...

```
<html>
<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="chartdiv" style="height:200px;width:300px; "></div>

  <script>
     $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);
  </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

I have carried out more analysis, and I have found I can execute standard javascript, but jQuery is not working. So, I am guessing that the problem is to do with loading of the script tags at the top of the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the JS files were being compiled, rather than simply being copied across. I found a similar issue here - [iPhone UIWebView local resources using Javascript and handling onorientationChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843820/iphone-uiwebview-local-resources-using-javascript-and-handling-onorientationchan).

The answer was to go to the Build Phases tab after clicking the main target, and moving the JS files from `Compile Sources` list to the `Copy Bundle Resources` list.