# JavaScript with iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, xcode, webview

I have a big problem
I work with HTML and JavaScript in WebView in my program. And everything seems to be nothing but he sees a Java script when I set the path to it

But if everyone in the javascript to put in html all working

Q: How do I properly set the path to the file javascript

***I found a solution. It's simple. My JavaScript file was in the wrong format. If you make it in UTF-8 all stand on the place
And it's really easy to add***

Comment: Are you asking how the `<script>` tag should look like to load a local javascript file from within your application bundle?

Comment: Possibly the same as this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843820/iphone-uiwebview-local-resources-using-javascript-and-handling-onorientationchan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file_name" ofType:@"file_type"];  
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
if (data) {  
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
  NSString *path = [bundle bundlePath];
  NSString *fullPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"file_name" ofType:@"file_type" inDirectory:path];
  [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath]]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard way is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="YourJSPath"></script>
```

Comment: This is correct, connected my java script on the WebView, but he refuses to turn it on

Comment: "Kiyura" prompted one of the options, because he truly is working, but my java script is huge, not very much like to insert it so I would like to link <script> but he does not want to see him

Answer (score 0):

and so, I fix this error. It was the fact that was written in Javascript Foreman not UTF-8 as I understand xCode only supports UTF-8